# How to display multiple columns which has value in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to display columns if it has value.
Some columns has values some of them don't.

I wrote below code. but it didn't work. 
Could you teach me how to write code please?

```
 @php
 if(!empty($image->wc)){
 echo "WC is ";  
 }
 @endphp
{{ $image->wc }} 

@php2
 if(!empty($image->w_type)){
 echo "W Type is ：";  
 }
 @endphp2
{{ $image->w_type }}
```

Comment: I am not clear your  @green

Comment: Sorry I edit my quesion as simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
@if(isset($image->wc))
    echo "WC is".{{$image->wc}};  
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.  I have a quesiton I would like to display $image->wc value too. How to write $image->wc in side of  @if ?

Comment: If you write inside `if` condition then use like `echo "WC is".{{$image->wc}};`

Comment: Thank you. I thoguth so but I got syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: How is it possible?? Never shows the error just three line.

Comment: Sorry for too long time. I figured out the reason my code had couple of blank space that makes error. Thank you very much for helping me.